# Chartjs in format Line is full points

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I would like to know how I can configure Chart Js so that instead of showing "mountains", only lines appear?

My actual chartjs line is:
[image]

My code is below:

```
var labels = ["25\/04","26\/04","27\/04","28\/04","29\/04","30\/04","01\/05","02\/05","03\/05","04\/05","05\/05","06\/05","07\/05","08\/05","09\/05","10\/05","11\/05","12\/05","13\/05","14\/05","15\/05","16\/05","17\/05","18\/05","19\/05","20\/05","21\/05","22\/05","23\/05","24\/05","25\/05"];
var datasets = [{"label":"Formul\u00e1rio Site","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"backgroundColor":"#4dc9f6","borderColor":"#4dc9f6"},{"label":"WhatsApp","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,24,47,24,2,4,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"backgroundColor":"#f67019","borderColor":"#f67019"},{"label":"Facebook","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"backgroundColor":"#f53794","borderColor":"#f53794"},{"label":"Call Tracking","data":[0,27,21,11,14,20,0,0,32,22,18,28,11,0,0,16,25,22,20,23,0,0,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"backgroundColor":"#537bc4","borderColor":"#537bc4"}];
var uniqueId = '60acaa981f364';  

var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: datasets
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Leads diários'
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: true,
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: true
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Dias'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Value'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById(uniqueId).getContext('2d');
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7brad1tu

I would like it to stay in this format, just the lines.
[image]

Comment: Remove te background color from your data.

Comment: @Grumpy that would also remove the background color of the points which in most cases is undesirable behaviour

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should add the property `line: false` to your dataset.

> For further details, please consult line [Dataset Properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) from Chart.js documentation

Answer (score 1):

In V3 of the lib this has become default behaviour, to achieve this in V2 you can do it in 2 ways, you can specify `fill: false` in every dataset or you can do it in the options for the line like so:

```js
options: {
  elements: {
    line: {
      fill: false
    }
  },
}
```

Example:

```js
var labels = ["25\/04", "26\/04", "27\/04", "28\/04", "29\/04", "30\/04", "01\/05", "02\/05", "03\/05", "04\/05", "05\/05", "06\/05", "07\/05", "08\/05", "09\/05", "10\/05", "11\/05", "12\/05", "13\/05", "14\/05", "15\/05", "16\/05", "17\/05", "18\/05", "19\/05", "20\/05", "21\/05", "22\/05", "23\/05", "24\/05", "25\/05"];
var datasets = [{
  "label": "Formul\u00e1rio Site",
  "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  "backgroundColor": "#4dc9f6",
  "borderColor": "#4dc9f6"
}, {
  "label": "WhatsApp",
  "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 24, 47, 24, 2, 4, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  "backgroundColor": "#f67019",
  "borderColor": "#f67019"
}, {
  "label": "Facebook",
  "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  "backgroundColor": "#f53794",
  "borderColor": "#f53794"
}, {
  "label": "Call Tracking",
  "data": [0, 27, 21, 11, 14, 20, 0, 0, 32, 22, 18, 28, 11, 0, 0, 16, 25, 22, 20, 23, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  "backgroundColor": "#537bc4",
  "borderColor": "#537bc4"
}];
var uniqueId = '60acaa981f364';

var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
      line: {
        fill: false
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Leads diários'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true,
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Dias'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Value'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById(uniqueId).getContext('2d');
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="60acaa981f364" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/6dL4ut85/1/